# Python: extract the href surrounding image

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using `bs4` and want to extract a `href` of a specified image. 
For example in the html code I have:

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="page/folder1/image.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="page_files/image.jpg" alt="Picture" border="0" width="150" height="150"></a></div>
</div>
```

And I have my image `src` given (`page_files/image.jpg`) and want to extract corresponding `href`, so in this example it is: `page/folder1/image.jpg`. I was trying to use `find_previous method`, but I have a small problem to extract the `href` content:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)
for img in soup('img'):
  imgLink = img.find_previous("a")
```

This returns the whole tag:

```
<a href="Here_is_link"><img alt="Tumblr" border="0" src="Here_is_source"/></a>
```

But I can't take the `href` content, because when I try to make:

```
imgLink = img.find_previous("a")['href']
```

I have an error.
The same thing is when I try to use `find_parent` like

```
imgLink = img.find_parent("a")['href']
```

How can I fix that? And what is better: `find_previous()` or `find_parent()`?

Comment: What error do you get? Your `img.find_parent('a')` should work *fine*. Perhaps not all your images are wrapped in the same `<a>` tags?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you misunderstood my question. ` img.find_parent('a')` works fine, but it returns : `<a href="Here_is_link"><img alt="Tumblr" border="0" src="Here_is_source"/></a>` But I want only to extract `href` content so here it is: `Here_is_link`. And the line `imgLink = img.find_parent("a")['href']` returns error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: That is because you are doing this for **all** images, and some of them do not *have* an `<a>` tag parent. The `find_parent()` search then returns `None` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are *only* looking for images that have a `<a>` parent tag with `href` attribute:

```
for img in soup.select('a[href] img'):
    link = img.find_parent('a', href=True)
    print link['href']
```

The [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) picks only images that have an `<a href="...">` parent tag *with an `href` attribute*. The `find_parent()` search then again limits the search to those tags that have the attribute set.

If you are searching for **all** images, chances are you are finding some that have a `<a>` tag parent or preceding tag that does not have the a `href` attribute; `<a>` tags can also be used for link targets with `<a name="...">`, for example. If you are getting `NoneType` attribute errors, that simply means *there is no such parent tag* for the given `<img>` tag.

Comment: @ Now I see what was the problem, I didn't paid attention that some images don't have the `<a>` parent tag. Thanks!